# I want to concat two strings for a TextView in android, Data Binding Api

Tags: android, android-layout, data-binding, android-databinding

Im using `DataBinding` Api for setting the views in android layouts. Here is my layout.

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <data>
    <variable name="user" type="testing.sampleapp.com.sampleapp.User"/>
  </data>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{ "Hello " + user.firstName}"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want the TextView to display **Hello UserName**. How to achieve this using the data binding api.

Answer (score 332, accepted):

concate it with **grave accent** (`)

```
android:text="@{`Hello ` + user.firstName}"/>
```

You can concat it in multiple ways, check it here [concat-two-strings-in-textview-using-databinding](http://tips.androidgig.com/concat-two-strings-in-textview-using-databinding/)

Comment: Yeah it worked. Thanks . I was using single inverted comma ('). Grave accent(`) worked for me.

Comment: @SasankSunkavalli glad to help you :) , always use grave accent for string when using DataBinding.

Comment: I don't get it. On my .xml this method, as well as any other methods on this page, is not even close to being functional. All it does is prints as : `@{`Hello ` + user.firstName}`

Comment: This is DataBinding?

Comment: Yes, @IgorGanapolsky. This falls under Android's databinding concept. Quick Reference: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding

Answer (score 101):

This is already answered by @GeorgeMount in comments to one of the solution. Which to me looks like the best solution so far here.

```
android:text="@{@string/location(user.city,user.state)}"
```

in your strings.xml

```
<string name="location">%1$s, %2$s</string>
```

Comment: great! thnx wery

Comment: thats what I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 13):

Since xml supports single quotes for values of attribute, you can also do this :

```
android:text='@{"Hello "+user.firstName}'
```

Answer (score 10):

**In case of static string and other dynamic you can use this**

```
android:text="@{`Hello ` + user.firstName}"/>
```

**In case of dynamic data you can use this.**

```
android:text='@{user.firstName+" "+user.lastName}'
```

Answer (score 8):

There are two ways.

**First Solution**

concat with grave accent (`)

```
android:text="@{`Hello ` + user.firstName}"/>
```

**Second Solution**

Declare Your string in `strings.xml`

like `"Hello %1$s , (whatever you want to add then add here)"`.

amd use `String.format(stringResource, upsatename);`

Comment: I know this would work, But i want to use the concat way

Comment: You can also use formatted string resources in the expression: `android:text="@{@string/hello(user.firstName)}"`

Comment: it's %1$s instead of %$1s... ;)

Answer (score 5):

To do a concat in xml layout:

```
<data>

/*This is used for android view*/
<import type="android.view.View" />

/*This is used for android resources*/
<import type="com.myapp.R" />

/*This is app context*/
<variable
    name="context"
    type="android.content.Context" />

/*This is used for model data*/
<variable
    name="item"
    type="com.myapp.models.Chapter" />
</data>

android:text="@{item.serialNo.concat(@string/space).concat(item.title)}"
```

In strings.xml I have added code for blank space:

```
<string name="space">\u0020</string>
```

Answer (score 5):

if you want to concat `String` resource with data from your model, you can do it in such way:

```
 android:text='@{@string/release_date+model.release_date}'
```

Answer (score 4):

Concat with the Backtick symbol `
Example:

```
android:text="@{product.price + `USD`}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Few cents from me

If you want to **check null and set default value** try this answer

```
 android:text='@{(user.first_name ?? "") +" "+ (user.last_name ?? "")}'
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I found to be is to replace ''(single) in place of ""(double),
For Eg. You have two variables,

```
<variable name="a" type="String" />
<variable name="b" type="String" />
```

Now to concatenate,

```
android:text='a + " " + b}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably late to the party:  Below code will also work

`android:text='@{@string/hello.concat(user.firstName)}'`

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue, this is what worked for me, hope it helps!!

android:text='@{"$"+String.valueOf(bean.payment_for==1?bean.price:bean.tip_amount)}'

Answer (score 0):

**activity_main,xml:**

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/word_count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/word_count"
        tools:text="3 of 10 story" />
```

**string.xml:**

```
<string name="word_count">%d of %d words</string>
```

**MainActivity.xml:**

```
binding.wordCount.text = getString(R.string.word_count, 3, 10)
```

**Output:**

[image]